# There is a set $A \subset [a,b]$ with $\lambda([a,b]-A)\leq \epsilon$ such that $f$ is uniformly bounded on $A$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> I try to prove:
>   Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable function. For every $\epsilon>0, $ there is a set $A \subset [a,b]$ with $\lambda([a,b]-A)\leq \epsilon$ such that $f$ is uniformly bounded on $A$($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure).

Can I set the $f:=\chi_{A}$?

Comment: Please do not deface your own question after it has received an answer. I rolled the edit back to when the question was complete. (Edit: I noticed you did this to a number of questions - I rolled them all back because this goes against the site's policies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_n = \{ x \in [a,b] | |f(x)| \le n \}$.

Clearly $\cup_n A_n = [a, b]$ and so $\lim_n mA_n = b-a$.

Comment: Does the uniformly bounded means $\mid f_n\mid\leq K$ for all $n$? So in your proof, why $f$ is uniformly bounded?

Comment: If $x \in A_n$ then $|f(x)| \le n$. I don't know what you mean by $f_n$.

Comment: What result can you get from your conclusion $\lim m(A_n) =b-a$?

Comment: What conclusion can you get? Read your question???

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. What is $A$? Is your $A_n$? And $\lim m(A_n)=b-a$ can conclude $f$ is uniformly bounded? Why?

Comment: You need to do some work. Pick $\epsilon>0$. Pick $n$ such that $\lambda([a,b] \setminus A_n) < \epsilon$. Then $f$ is bounded (uniform is redundant) by $n$ on $A_n$.

Comment: Yes, if let $\lambda([a,b]-A_n)<\epsilon2^{-n}$, then $\lambda([a,b]-A)<\epsilon$. And $\lim_n \lambda(A_n)=b-a$ means $f$ uniformly bounded? How about the next step?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have no idea where you are pulling the $2^{-n}$ from. The $\lim_n$ doesn't mean that $f$ is uniformly bounded. $f$ is only bounded on $A_n$. What next step???

Comment: Ok, do you mean $A=\cup_n A_n$? then $\lambda([a,b]-A)<\lambda([a,b]-A_n)<\epsilon$ and $f$ is uniformly bounded on the set $A$.  But I confused about $f$ is bouneded by $n$ on each $A_n$. How about the $A$? $f $ is bounded?

Comment: No. $A$ will be set to one of the $A_n$ that satisfies $\lambda([a,b] \setminus A_n) < \epsilon$. Then, on this $A=A_n$, we have $|f(x)| \le n$.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks.